# In PHP, if I find a word in a file, can I make the line that the word came from into a $string

Tags: php, string, file, line, strpos

I want to find a word in a large list file.

Then, if and when that word is found, take the whole line of the list file that the word was found in?

so far I have not seen any PHP string functions to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use a line-delimited regular expression to find the word, then your match will contain the whole line.

Something like:

```
preg_match('^.*WORD.*$, $filecontents, $matches);
```

Then `$matches` will have the full lines of the places it found `WORD`

Answer (score 1):

You could use preg_match:

```
$arr = array();
preg_match("/^.*yourSearch.*$/", $fileContents, $arr);
```

`$arr` will then contain the matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = "/path/to/wordlist.txt";
$word = "Word";

$handle = fopen($path,'r');
$currentline = 1;  //in case you want to know which line you got it from
while(!feof($handle))
{
    $line = fgets($handle);
    if(strpos($line,$word))
    {
        $lines[$currentline] = $line;
    }
    $currentline++;
}
fclose($handle);
```

If you want to only find a single line where the word occurs, then instead of saving it to an array, save it somewhere and just `break` after the match is made.

This should work quickly on files of any size (using file() on large files probably isn't good)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$searhString = "search";
$result = preg_grep("/^.*{$searhString}.*$/", file('/path/to/your/file.txt'));
print_r($result);
```

Explanation:

- [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will read your file and produces array of lines
- [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) will return array element in which matching pattern is found
- `$result` is the resulting array.